# Why am I Getting a no connection Error when I Implement an Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mvp

I am creating a desktop application using c# WinForms and Entity Framework. I'm trying to decouple my view from the presenter with events and when I do it breaks something. I get an error "No connection string named 'TipManagerDBEntities' could be found in the application config file" when I click on Form1.cs.

I checked the App.config file to make sure the connection string is in there and I made sure the config file was loading up with the solution. I've reset my repo to right before I made the event changes and everything works fine. I then rewrite the event and it runs fine. When I save and reopen the project I get the error. When I debug the program it still runs fine but I can't seem to find the source of the error.

**This is the call stack for the error:**

```
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
at TipManager.Services.Repository.GetSumOfDeposits() in C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TipManager\Services\Repository.cs:line 15
at TipManager.Services.TipManagerServices.passSumTotalToModel() in C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TipManager\Services\TipManagerServices.cs:line 22
at TipManager.Presenter.HomePresenter.DisplayTotal() in C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TipManager\Presenter\HomePresenter.cs:line 34
at TipManager.Presenter.HomePresenter.OnHomeLoaded(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TipManager\Presenter\HomePresenter.cs:line 56
at TipManager.UserControls.Home.Home_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TipManager\UserControls\Home.cs:line 40
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)
```

**The App.config file containing the connection string:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TipManagerDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-GNG12RP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TipManagerDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**The View with an IHome interface:**

```
public partial class Home : UserControl, IHome
    {
        //private HomePresenter presenter;

        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new HomePresenter(this);

        }
        private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
            //presenter.DisplayTotal();
            EventHandler handler = homeLoaded;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

**The Presenter:**

```
class HomePresenter
{
    TipManagerModel tipManager = new TipManagerModel();

    TipManagerServices services;

    private IHome homeView;

    public HomePresenter(IHome view)
    {
        homeView = view;
        services = new TipManagerServices(tipManager);
        homeView.homeLoaded += new EventHandler(OnHomeLoaded);
    }

    public void OnHomeLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTotal();
    }
```

Oddly enough everything is still working as expected but I get a big error page blocking my designer with the option to Ignore and Continue but I'd like to get to the root of the problem. In the View when I use the commented out code to create and call the Presenter itself I don't get this error but when I use the event this happens every time. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event had nothing to do with the problem. The connection string was the problem. First, I copied the connection string from the app.config file, excluding the provider name part at the end and changed "&quot" with "'". Then passed the string directly to the base constructor in the context file like so:

```
public partial class TipManagerDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public TipManagerDBEntities()
        : base(@"metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';data source=DESKTOP-GNG12RP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TipManagerDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework';")
    {
    }
```

Honestly, I don't know exactly why this fixed the problem. The program was still able to connect to the database and query data but you would get an error.